# Solving for volume using washer and cylindrical shell method

Tags: calculus, integration

We are required to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region enclosed by the given curves about the specified line using both the washer and cylindrical shell method.

1) y = $e^{2x}$, y = 4 and y-axis; about the x-axis.

2) y = $x^3$, y = 0 and x = 2; about the x-axis.

I am having difficulties understanding the question. How do we go about solving such questions?

Guiding me towards the right direction is sufficient. All help and suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic setup for revolving $1)$ about the $x$-axis in both methods:

**Washer:**

- $$\pi\int^b_0(4^2-y^2)dx,\text{ where }b\text{ is the solution of }e^{2x}=4$$

**Cylindrical:**

- $$2\pi\int^8_0 yxdy=2\pi\int^8_0 y\sqrt[3]{y}dy$$